# Duda con Git al momento de copiar, no clonar

Tags: git, git-commit

Tengo un problema con git, en mi PC, cree ramas locales y tenia todo ahi, pero mi pc dejo de funcionar, asi que cambie de pc, pero necesito  llevarme mis ramas locales.

Lo que hice fue copiar la carpeta del proyecto al nuevo pc, el problema es que como no use `git clone`, todos los archivos que copie aparecen como "no trackeados", y debo hacer add y commit, pero no puedo hacer eso porque pues esos cambios ya están en el repositorio remoto.

Cómo puedo hacer para que git me haga el seguimiento pero sin hacer add y commit?

Estaba pensando en usar git restore, pero no estoy seguro de los efectos del mismo.

Comment: Todo el "trackeo" que efectua git, se encuentra en una sub-carpeta `.git` dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. Dicha carpeta es "invisible",  es posible que hayas copiado todos los archivos, menos esa carpeta.

Comment: la carpeta .git si esta en el nuevo pc. lo que quiero es encontrar una forma de decrile a git que este es el nuevo local, que esos arhivos copiados ya estan con commit

Comment: Si es así, entonces cabe la posibilidad de que quizás te hayas olvidado de realizar un commit en la computadora anterior. Si haces `git log`, puedes visualizar el ultimo commit que has realizado. Al mismo tiempo revisa las "ramas" que creaste con `git branch`.

Comment: pues me asegure de dejar limpio todo, sin ningun cambio antes de copiar la carpeta, el problema es que pues como son archivos nuevos me los detecta como no trackeados pero copie exactamente la carpeta

Comment: y qué hay dentro de la carpeta `.git`  en el PC nuevo? Cuando hiciste `git log` te muestra algo? ¿Seguro que te pide añadirlos y no comittearlos solamente?

Comment: Cuando dices que copiaste la carpeta ¿te refieres también a la carpeta .git? Tienes que copiarlo todo incluyendo esa carpeta. Los síntomas que describen me hacen pensar que no fue esto lo que hiciste, sino que creaste una carpeta vacía en el nuevo PC, la "inicializaste" con git para control de versiones, y luego copiaste todos los archivos del PC viejo a éste. Una forma de verificar si estoy en lo cierto sería hacer un `git log` y ver si muestra algo en la historia. Si realmente habías copiado la carpeta .git del viejo debería mostrarte el historial del viejo. Si no, no habrá historial.

Comment: yo uso wamp como server local, lo que hice fue dejar mi repositorio limpio en el pc viejo, y luego copie toda la carpeta de www, cuando hago git branch, me muestra todas las ramas, y en git log si aparecen los commit, y con git stauts me muestra que debo hacer git add y git commit. y pues obviamente no puedo hacer eso, porque todos esos cambios ya estan en el repo remoto